# How do I put the citations at the end of a document in a tufte handout?

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, tufte, bookdown

I'm using `bookdown::tufte_html2()` to create a single-document bookdown document, and while I love all the Tufte features, I'd like my citations *not* to clutter the margins.

The `tufte` package documentation seems to suggest [this is optional]:

> References can be displayed as margin notes for HTML output. For example, we can cite R here (R Core Team 2015R Core Team. 2015. R: A Language and Environment for Statistical Computing. Vienna, Austria: R Foundation for Statistical Computing. https://www.R-project.org/.). To enable this feature, you must set link-citations: yes in the YAML metadata, and the version of pandoc-citeproc should be at least 0.7.2. You can always install your own version of Pandoc from http://pandoc.org/installing.html if the version is not sufficient. To check the version of pandoc-citeproc in your system, you may run this in R:
>
> `system2('pandoc-citeproc', '--version')`
>
> If your version of pandoc-citeproc is too low, or you did not set link-citations: yes in YAML, references in the HTML output will be placed at the end of the output document.

I've set

```
link_citations: false
```

in my YAML header, but to no avail.

The `tufte_html2()` output *still* has the citations in the margins.

Oddly, `tufte_handout2()` also does not react to the argument, and simply *always* places the citations at the end of the document.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

Two problems here. One on my side and one on yours. It is `link-citations` instead of `link_citations`. Then you can

```
devtools::install_github(c('rstudio/tufte', 'rstudio/bookdown'))
```

Without setting `link-citations` (default is false), or setting `link-citations: no`, you should see citations at the end of your document instead of the margin.